# Set Html.HiddenFor property in nested viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get the value of `GroupGameId` in my model when posting/submitting, but the value is showing 0 (even after using `HiddenFor`). I have verified that the `HttpGet` is setting the value of `GroupGameId` properly, and that it is received by the view.

**ViewModels**

```
public class GameAssignerModel
{
    // Other properties here....
    public List<GameAssignerTableModel> GameAssignerTable { get; set; }
}

public class GameAssignerTableModel
{
    public int GroupGameId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GameName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsAssigned { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UnAssignedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.GameAssignerTable.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].GroupGameId)
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.GameAssignerTable[i].GameName</td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].IsAssigned)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].UnAssignedDate, new {id = "UnassignedDate" + i})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

**Edit:** The data is being submitted through ajax first, I don't know if that matters. I have verified that it is hitting the POST action in my controller and that the rest of the model data is being submitted correctly.

```
    if ($("#assignGames").valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $("#assignModal").modal("hide");
                    location.reload();
                }
```

Comment: *I am trying to get the value of GroupGameId in my model when posting/submitting, but the value is showing 0* You have to add your post method

Comment: When debugging and I put my mouse over the model, or add the model to the watch list I can see that the value for `GroupGameId` is 0. It is just an `ActionResult` with `HttpPost`, having the model as the parameter

Comment: Post your Action method and is your table wrapped in form tag?

Comment: @mxmissile yes it is in a form tag, and see the comment above. I don't think the action is necessary but if you want I can post it

Comment: Do any of the other form values work? ("IsAssigned" etc)

Comment: Yes I am getting the values for them correctly

Comment: I am submitting the data through ajax, I do not know if that matters though

Comment: That helps. Try moving the HiddenFor outside of the table if you can. I'm wondering if jquery is just not picking it up for some reason. Have you looked at he actual parameters being posted? In your browser: F12 -> Network.

Comment: Have you verified the id sent over in the network request? Again, show us your post action.

Comment: your GroupGameId is primary key of table? you are geeting value from  controller?

Comment: I fixed it by putting the `HiddenFor` inside the `<td>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by putting `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].GroupGameId)` inside the `<td>` tag of `GameName`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.GameAssignerTable.Count(); i++)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.GameAssignerTable[i].GameName
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].GroupGameId)
    </td>

        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].IsAssigned)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GameAssignerTable[i].UnAssignedDate, new {id = "UnassignedDate" + i})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Note that the reason this works is that `<input>` is not a valid sibling for `<tr>`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you inspect the input html element in the browser, you will see the problem. The name property will likely be incorrect. To fix, you can add the extra parameter for the hiddenfor element:

```
new {Name = "GroupGameId"}
```

That should fix posting for that element.